# Counting and computing the average length of words in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, average

I'm trying to debug a program in ruby that is meant to compute and print the average length of words in an array.

```
words = ['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago', 'our', 'fathers', 'brought', 'forth', 'on', 'this', 'continent', 'a', 'new', 'nation', 'conceived', 'in', 'Liberty', 'and', 'dedicated', 'to', 'the', 'proposition', 'that', 'all', 'men', 'are', 'created', 'equal']

word_lengths = Array.new

words.each do |word|

  word_lengths << word_to.s

end

sum = 0
word_lengths.each do |word_length|
  sum += word_length
end
average = sum.to_s/length.size
puts "The average is " + average.to_s
```

Obviously, the code is not working. When I run the program, I receive an error message that says the string '+' can't be coerced into fixnum (typeerror).

What do I do no make the code compute the average length of the strings in the array?

Comment: What is `word_to`? What is `s`? What is `length`?

Answer (score 7):

**Try**:

```
words.join.length.to_f / words.length
```

**Explanation:**

This takes advantage of *chaining* methods together. First, `words.join` gives a string of all the characters from the array:

```
'Fourscoreandsevenyearsagoourfathersbroughtforthonthiscontinentanewnationconcei
vedinLibertyanddedicatedtothepropositionthatallmenarecreatedequal'
```

We then we apply `length.to_f` giving the length as a float (using a float ensures an accurate final result):

```
143.0
```

We then divide the above using `/ words.length`:

```
4.766666666666667
```

Comment: You can also use [`fdiv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-fdiv) to get a floating point result: `words.join.length.fdiv(words.length)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
words = ['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago', 'our', 'fathers',
 'brought', 'forth', 'on', 'this', 'continent', 'a', 'new', 'nation',
 'conceived', 'in', 'Liberty', 'and', 'dedicated', 'to', 'the', 'proposition',
 'that', 'all', 'men', 'are', 'created', 'equal']


sum = 0
words.each do |word|
  sum += word.length

end

average = sum.to_i/words.size
puts "The average is " + average.to_s
```

You don't have to have a separate `word_lengths` variable to keep all the sizes of words in `words` array. Without looping through the `word_lengths` array you can merge both loops into one loop as I have given in the post.

The way you're getting the length of the `word` is wrong. Use `word.length`. See [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-length).

Comment: Since the user is new, can you please add comments.  His problems were with the functions of the array.  Please explain the functions of the array words. such as word.length versus using something like words.size which you use to compute the average.  Since he is new and due to the naming convention he chose in his "do" loop it is not intuitive.

Comment: @Bunti Thanks! you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Prefer `sum = words.reduce(0) {|sum, word| sum + word.length }`.

Comment: @Jordan `reduce` works nicely with `map`, e.g. `words.map(&:length).reduce(:+)`

Comment: @Stefan Indeed it does, although I reflexively avoid iterating over the same data structure more than once if I can avoid it. In this instance (with such a small array) it makes no difference, though, and your version is nice and readable, so .