# Ruby simple Array/Iterator?

Tags: ruby

I have a story written in a .txt file and I have to count the number of letters and words then divide both in order to find average. I am unable to find a total number of letters or the total number of words. When I run my program, Ruby shows me a list of numbers but I think that is number of letters per word. I'm looking for TOTAL letters so I'm not sure how to make Ruby add everything. Here is code. Also is the iterator to count total number of words ".count" ?

```
myfile = File.new("story.txt", "r")
contents = myfile.read
wordlist = contents.split
wordlist.each do |length|
puts length.size.to_s
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting and computing the average length of words in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331077/counting-and-computing-the-average-length-of-words-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

> Also is the iterator to count total number of words ".count" ?

No.  `count()` is a String method, which you can read about in the [String docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count).

On the other hand, [each()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each) is an iterator.

You can get the `length` or `size` of a string, which are described in the [String docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-length).

So, you could do something like this:

```
words = %w[ a to cat ]  #shortcut for ["a", "to", "cat"]
                        #Saves you from having to type all those quotes.
letter_count = 0
word_count = 0

words.each do |word|
  word_count += 1
  letter_count += word.length
end

puts "The count of words is: #{word_count}"
puts "The total number of letters is: #{letter_count}"

--output:--
The count of words is: 3
The total number of letters is: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Doe,

If you want to get the total number of letters and words from your .txt file you can simply use the `.split()` method from Ruby's string class which is the return value of myfile.read`.

To get the count of all letters in the story.txt, we can use

`contents.split("")`.

We are giving the split method`.split()`' an empty string as an argument telling Ruby to split that string into the most pieces possible.

`contents.split("")` returns something like this:

`=> ["t", "h", "i", "s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "a", "n", " ", "e", "x", "a", "m", "p", "l", "e", " ", "s", "t", "o", "r", "y"]` yeah?

so next to finish the things off we use the `.split()` method which returns an array upon which we can call the Array class's `.length` method. The `.length` method returns the number of elements in an array. 
In this case we get 
`=> 24`

For word count we'd repeat the process above only we tell ruby to `split(" ")`with `" "` a space in the quotation.

So to get the word count and the letter count in the .txt we can write something like

```
myfile = File.new("file.txt", "r")
contents = myfile.read
word_list = contents.split(" ")#returns an array of words
word_count = word_list.length# returns number all words in the text file
letter_list = contents.split("")#returns an array of letters
letter_count = letter_list.length#returns number of all letters in the text file
```

Comment: This code worked! Is it possible to make this work in a "for" loop?

Comment: Absolutely, I recommend Ruby's .each() method. It's basically a for loop but with all the syntactic sugar that Ruby has to offer. An example might be: word_list.each {|word|  word_count += word.length }